# How to check if an excel file has unreadable content in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my web application, I get emails from many users and each email has excel attachment 2007.The attachments are saved in the server and I need to parse each email attachment through PHPEXcelReader class. But there are excel attachments with the unreadable contents which throws the following error.
        error: ZipArchive::getForName();Invalid or unutillized zip object.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader = setLoadSheetOnly('Sheet1');
$directory = "email_attachments";
$file_name = "attachment1.xlsx";
if(file_Exists($directory."/".$file_name))
{ 
       // This following line is not executed, and throws the error.
       $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($directory."/".$file_name);

}
```

The attachment1.xlsx can not be opened and give an alert that the file has unreadable contents.
how to solve this issue? 

please help.

Comment: So do we have to guess what your code looks like?

Comment: If the condition is matched, so then check your file content, to see if it's not corrupted file. Can you open the file without any alert using Microsoft Excel?

Comment: I'm rather lost, because there is no call to any method called `getForName()` anywhere in PHPExcel (nor is no mention to a method of that name anywhere in the ZipArchive class either according to the PHP Docs)

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you running? Where did you get it? Does it work with any files at all? What does the IOFactory `identify()` method return for these files?